# странное поведение padding

Tags: html, css, padding

Не понимаю почему padding в классе *wrapper* действуют, как margin, хочу сделать отступы с левой и правой стороны внутри блока , а отступы появляются вокруг. Вроде бы вложено все правильно. В верстке новичок, по-этому прошу строго не судить)

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  background-color: #282828;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px;
}


/* header */

.bg_h {
  background-color: #000;
}

header {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
}

header>a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 150px;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar_head {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.sidebar_head a {
  color: #c9c9c9;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  margin-left: 43px;
}


/*header end*/

.block_1 {
  height: 640px;
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
}

.modern {
  height: 640px;
  background-image: url(img/Logo_modern.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 140px 110px;
  /*    padding-left: 140px;*/
  padding-right: 140px;
}

.block_1 span {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.block_1 img {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.block_1 p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #c6c6c6;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.modern>button {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 13px 28px;
  border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
  margin-top: 45px;
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
}

.form {
  float: right;
  width: 362px;
  height: 362px;
  margin-top: 140px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.but_1 {
  width: 362px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.but_2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #ff9b51;
  height: 53px;
  width: 362px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 44px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

.form input {
  margin: 0 40px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  width: 275px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-left: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
  border-right: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
}

.social_media {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
  outline-bottom: solid 1px #d6d6d6;
  padding: 22px 83px 20px 140px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.social_media h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #282828;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.social_media p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #a9aaac;
}

.icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 54px;
  float: right;
  margin: 7px 45px auto 0;
}

.rss {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -591px center;
}

.znak {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -483px center;
}

.inst {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -376px center;
}

.pi {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -272px center;
}

.goog {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -183px center;
}

.twit {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -76px center;
}

.fb {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat 20px center;
}

.tab_soft {
  height: 590px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_h">
  <header>
    <a href="index.html"> <img src="img/logo.png"></a>
    <ul class="sidebar_head">
      <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block_1 ">
    <div class=" modern">
      <div class="form">
        <ul>
          <li><button class="but_1">Try Your FREE Trial Today</button></li>
          <li><input type="text" placeholder="Name"></li>
          <li><input type="email" placeholder="Email"></li>
          <li><input type="password" placeholder="Password"></li>
          <li><button class="but_2">Get Started</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <span>MODERN AXURE TEMPLATE <br> FOR BEAUTIFUL PROTOTYPES</span>
      <img src="img/modern_line.png" alt="">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean <br> euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus <br> accumsan et viverra justo commodo.
      </p>
      <button>Download</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="social_media">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon rss"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon znak"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon inst"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon pi"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon goog"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon twit"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon fb"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Social Media</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br> Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
  </div>
  <!--social_media END  -->
  <div class="tab_soft">
    <p>dasdawsdaw</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У вас всё верно работает. Вы устанавливаете padding у `.wrapper`, который имеет цвет фона #282828 и является окружением всех внутренний блоков. Чтобы сделать нормальный отступ, вам нужно добавить отступ ещё в его внутренние блоки `.block_1` и `.tab_soft`.

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  background-color: #282828;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px;
}


/* header */

.bg_h {
  background-color: #000;
}

header {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
}

header>a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 150px;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar_head {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.sidebar_head a {
  color: #c9c9c9;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  margin-left: 43px;
}


/*header end*/

.block_1 {
  height: 640px;
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
  padding: 100px;
}

.modern {
  height: 640px;
  background-image: url(img/Logo_modern.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 140px 110px;
  /*    padding-left: 140px;*/
  padding-right: 140px;
}

.block_1 span {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.block_1 img {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.block_1 p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #c6c6c6;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.modern>button {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 13px 28px;
  border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
  margin-top: 45px;
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
}

.form {
  float: right;
  width: 362px;
  height: 362px;
  margin-top: 140px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.but_1 {
  width: 362px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.but_2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #ff9b51;
  height: 53px;
  width: 362px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 44px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

.form input {
  margin: 0 40px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  width: 275px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-left: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
  border-right: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
}

.social_media {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
  outline-bottom: solid 1px #d6d6d6;
  padding: 22px 83px 20px 140px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.social_media h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #282828;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.social_media p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #a9aaac;
}

.icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 54px;
  float: right;
  margin: 7px 45px auto 0;
}

.rss {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -591px center;
}

.znak {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -483px center;
}

.inst {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -376px center;
}

.pi {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -272px center;
}

.goog {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -183px center;
}

.twit {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -76px center;
}

.fb {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat 20px center;
}

.tab_soft {
  height: 590px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_h">
  <header>
    <a href="index.html"> <img src="img/logo.png"></a>
    <ul class="sidebar_head">
      <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block_1 ">
    <div class=" modern">
      <div class="form">
        <ul>
          <li><button class="but_1">Try Your FREE Trial Today</button></li>
          <li><input type="text" placeholder="Name"></li>
          <li><input type="email" placeholder="Email"></li>
          <li><input type="password" placeholder="Password"></li>
          <li><button class="but_2">Get Started</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <span>MODERN AXURE TEMPLATE <br> FOR BEAUTIFUL PROTOTYPES</span>
      <img src="img/modern_line.png" alt="">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean <br> euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus <br> accumsan et viverra justo commodo.
      </p>
      <button>Download</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="social_media">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon rss"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon znak"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon inst"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon pi"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon goog"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon twit"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon fb"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Social Media</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br> Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
  </div>
  <!--social_media END  -->
  <div class="tab_soft">
    <p>dasdawsdaw</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

***Ещё варианты решений***

1. Если у родителя будет такой же padding, как и у дочерних элементов, то можно воспользоваться значением *inherit* у padding

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  background-color: #282828;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px;
}


/* header */

.bg_h {
  background-color: #000;
}

header {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
}

header>a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 150px;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar_head {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.sidebar_head a {
  color: #c9c9c9;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  margin-left: 43px;
}


/*header end*/

.block_1 {
  height: 640px;
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
  padding: inherit;
}

.modern {
  height: 640px;
  background-image: url(img/Logo_modern.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 140px 110px;
  /*    padding-left: 140px;*/
  padding-right: 140px;
}

.block_1 span {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.block_1 img {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.block_1 p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #c6c6c6;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.modern>button {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 13px 28px;
  border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
  margin-top: 45px;
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
}

.form {
  float: right;
  width: 362px;
  height: 362px;
  margin-top: 140px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.but_1 {
  width: 362px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.but_2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #ff9b51;
  height: 53px;
  width: 362px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 44px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

.form input {
  margin: 0 40px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  width: 275px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-left: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
  border-right: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
}

.social_media {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
  outline-bottom: solid 1px #d6d6d6;
  padding: 22px 83px 20px 140px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.social_media h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #282828;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.social_media p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #a9aaac;
}

.icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 54px;
  float: right;
  margin: 7px 45px auto 0;
}

.rss {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -591px center;
}

.znak {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -483px center;
}

.inst {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -376px center;
}

.pi {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -272px center;
}

.goog {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -183px center;
}

.twit {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -76px center;
}

.fb {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat 20px center;
}

.tab_soft {
  height: 590px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_h">
  <header>
    <a href="index.html"> <img src="img/logo.png"></a>
    <ul class="sidebar_head">
      <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block_1 ">
    <div class=" modern">
      <div class="form">
        <ul>
          <li><button class="but_1">Try Your FREE Trial Today</button></li>
          <li><input type="text" placeholder="Name"></li>
          <li><input type="email" placeholder="Email"></li>
          <li><input type="password" placeholder="Password"></li>
          <li><button class="but_2">Get Started</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <span>MODERN AXURE TEMPLATE <br> FOR BEAUTIFUL PROTOTYPES</span>
      <img src="img/modern_line.png" alt="">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean <br> euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus <br> accumsan et viverra justo commodo.
      </p>
      <button>Download</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="social_media">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon rss"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon znak"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon inst"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon pi"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon goog"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon twit"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon fb"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Social Media</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br> Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
  </div>
  <!--social_media END  -->
  <div class="tab_soft">
    <p>dasdawsdaw</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Ещё есть вариант создать отдельный класс с этим отступом и применить его всем нужным блокам.

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  background-color: #282828;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px;
}


/* header */

.bg_h {
  background-color: #000;
}

header {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
}

header>a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 150px;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar_head {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.sidebar_head a {
  color: #c9c9c9;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  margin-left: 43px;
}


/*header end*/

.block_1 {
  height: 640px;
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
}

.modern {
  height: 640px;
  background-image: url(img/Logo_modern.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 140px 110px;
  /*    padding-left: 140px;*/
  padding-right: 140px;
}

.block_1 span {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.block_1 img {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.block_1 p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #c6c6c6;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.modern>button {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 13px 28px;
  border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
  margin-top: 45px;
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
}

.form {
  float: right;
  width: 362px;
  height: 362px;
  margin-top: 140px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.but_1 {
  width: 362px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.but_2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #ff9b51;
  height: 53px;
  width: 362px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 44px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

.form input {
  margin: 0 40px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  width: 275px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-left: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
  border-right: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
}

.social_media {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
  outline-bottom: solid 1px #d6d6d6;
  padding: 22px 83px 20px 140px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.social_media h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #282828;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.social_media p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #a9aaac;
}

.icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 54px;
  float: right;
  margin: 7px 45px auto 0;
}

.rss {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -591px center;
}

.znak {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -483px center;
}

.inst {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -376px center;
}

.pi {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -272px center;
}

.goog {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -183px center;
}

.twit {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat -76px center;
}

.fb {
  background: url(img/social-media-icons.png) no-repeat 20px center;
}

.tab_soft {
  height: 590px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.padding--100 {
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_h">
  <header>
    <a href="index.html"> <img src="img/logo.png"></a>
    <ul class="sidebar_head">
      <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block_1 padding--100">
    <div class=" modern">
      <div class="form">
        <ul>
          <li><button class="but_1">Try Your FREE Trial Today</button></li>
          <li><input type="text" placeholder="Name"></li>
          <li><input type="email" placeholder="Email"></li>
          <li><input type="password" placeholder="Password"></li>
          <li><button class="but_2">Get Started</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <span>MODERN AXURE TEMPLATE <br> FOR BEAUTIFUL PROTOTYPES</span>
      <img src="img/modern_line.png" alt="">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean <br> euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus <br> accumsan et viverra justo commodo.
      </p>
      <button>Download</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="social_media">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon rss"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon znak"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon inst"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon pi"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon goog"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon twit"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="icon fb"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Social Media</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br> Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
  </div>
  <!--social_media END  -->
  <div class="tab_soft padding--100">
    <p>dasdawsdaw</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а я хочу сделать один padding для всей страницы сразу, нужно создать отдельный див и поместить все туда?

Comment: @toxa404, всё равно вряд ли выйдет. Если вы хотите использовать один отступ везде, то создаёте отдельный класс с padding и поставьте его нужным элементам

Comment: я думал , что сделать один для всех будет правильнее чем каждый раз вписывать отступ

Comment: @toxa404, у вас блоки имеют свои цвета, если вы всем сделаете общий отступ, то возникнет даже проблема, что была выше указана.

Comment: понятно, спасибо. А ещё вопрос я в верстке новичек , код слишком ужасный?

Comment: @toxa404, вполне нормальный :) Но я сейчас используют специальную расстановку классов. `<div class="parent"><div class="parent-children"><button class="parent-children-little_button"></button></div></div>` - такую, примерно, чтобы избежать нагромождений в CSS.

Comment: @toxa404, и ещё у тебя там в пером классе, где описаны все атрибуты элементов, можно заменить на `* {margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;}`. `*` - это все элементы

Comment: @toxa404, ужасный.

Comment: @Yuri, вот именно поэтому и возникает нагроможденный код css